# cannot understand the Javascript setter and getter lookup in classes

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter

I understand that JavaScript classes are syntactic sugar over prototypes and not works as pure classes in other OOP languages. But the problem here arises is on the getter and setter. When completely leaving getter and setter in the child class, it behaves normally but if I define any one of getter or setter broke these.

For example:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.__value = "Default";
    }

    set value(value) {
        console.log("setter called")
        this.__value = value;
    }
    
    get value() {
        console.log("getter called")
        return this.__value;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    
}

let b = new B();
b.value = 2;
console.log(b.value);
```

The above code works fine but if I define getter or setter in the child class the lookup won't go to parent class. I googled about it and found that, it is intentional and is ES standard. Then why when the child class has no methods the lookup reaches the parent class and able to access the getter and setter?

Answer (score 2):

When you access an object property, either to set a value `obj.prop = 'val'` or to retrieve a value `console.log(obj.prop)`, the engine will try to find that property in the object's prototype chain.

It starts at the instance. In this case, the instance doesn't have any properties, so it continues.

The next object is the instance's internal prototype, which is `B.prototype`. If `B` has the property name being looked at, it'll stop there. If there's a setter, and a value was assigned to the property, the setter will be invoked. If there's a getter, and the value being retrieved, the getter will be invoked.

That's it - once a property is found in the prototype chain, it'll stop searching.

If `B.prototype` didn't have the setter/getter, then the engine would proceed to the *next* object. The internal prototype of `B.prototype` is `A.prototype`. Then, `A`'s setter or getter would be invoked.

It's possible to invoke the superclass's setters/getters from the child, but it looks a bit strange:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.__value = "Default";
    }

    set value(value) {
        console.log("setter called")
        this.__value = value;
    }
    
    get value() {
        console.log("getter called")
        return this.__value;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    set value(value) {
        console.log('sub setter calling super');
        super.value = value;
    }
    get value() {
        console.log('sub getter calling super');
        return super.value;
    }
}

let b = new B();
b.value = 2;
console.log(b.value);
```

Comment: Is this specific to accessors like (get and set) because the other method lookup works perfectly?

Comment: No, the same thing applies to all properties. Eg if the instance has `{ prop: 'foo' }` and `B.prototype` has `{ prop: 'bar' }`, and you try to access `instance.prop`, you'll get `foo`; the engine stops looking once the first object in the chain that has the property is found.

Comment: Yes I understand it after recreating it in own way.Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dr03v2zg/

Answer (score 1):

After googling and lot of code execution I found an answer to my own question,If we define no accessors(getter or setter) in our child class the lookup will proceed towards the parent but if we set any accessor using the `get` or `set` descriptor in child class that will invoke the `Object.defineProperty` method and set the descriptor we mentioned.If we have both setter and getter there is no problem,but if we leave any one that leads to missing of those property in our current object.That's the reason why we get `undefined` as the undefined property gets `undefined` value.So literally we have found the value which is `undefined` thats the main reason we cannot proceed to the parent prototype as value(`undefined`) found in the current object and  the lookup will stop.